# Deck footing close to the edge of a short retaining wall

Tags: deck, footings

The middle of three deck posts will be within a few inches of the edge of a 24 inch retaining wall. This is in a temperate area (Seattle) and the ground basically never freezes more than an inch or two.   My thoughts:

- County (permitting) should have no problem with the situation if I dig down 24 + 20 inches = 44 inches, put a few inches of gravel and then a full 48 inch tube of concrete - which puts us 4 inches above grade.  That's 44 inches of concrete below ground including 20 inches below the bottom of grade *below the retaining wall*.

I do believe based on a past discussion that the permitting officer will tell me flat out that is overkill. In any case lets consider this the safe/fallback approach.   It is a *lot* of concrete.

- Alternatively: dig down the same depth, but place a few more inches of gravel, so that the concrete portion is maybe forty inches or high thirties instead of a full 48. In that case the concrete still reaches below the *bottom of the retaining wall* but only by single digit inches instead of 20.  I believe that should be plenty structurally but will be soliciting comments [and approval] for same.
- Other thoughts?

** Update I did find this resource that shows that the IBC condones my thoughts of using a concrete "channel" wider than the post but narrower than the footer  to connect the post to the footer.

It is also the case that my solution references the specific footer calculations and thus is a carefully considered one.  It exceeds what the County Permitter has said would meet the requirements.

This question appears to have been closed in response to my questioning the need to go down 40+ inches below grade - suggested by another answerer in Minnesota - when Seattle area is relatively temperate and does not have 40 to 48 inch frostlines like they do.
[image]

Comment: @crip659  Yes and I specified the local conditions about near to edge of a retaining wall. This does not follow a typical path to calculate the depth: the permitting office will not have a canned response on it.

Comment: Beside a retaining wall or beside a house foundation for an addition, should be almost the same.  It depends on how much you trust the retaining wall not to give way.

Comment: @crip659  Think about it.  Retaining wall is constructed for a given load. If we just put a pier pad from 12 inches below grade to grade - and especially near the _edge_ of the wall thats potentially a large amount of additional lateral pressure . The wall *will* give way unless it were heavily over engineered to begin with.  The answers I am working on transfer the pressure to below the level of the retaining wall entirely

Comment: had my engineer want my deck footing to go to same grade as my house footings to avoid the lateral pressure - was going to be a lot of concrete - when I challenged him he backed down and decided there won't really be a lot of load on the deck and the lateral load on the 8" pour concrete rebar re-inforced foundation wall would easily handle it.  agree with your retaining wall could be crap but I'd take the alternate approach you suggest as the load is transferred lower than bottom of wall in that case too.

Comment: Is the distance to the retaining wall more, or less, than the depth requirement *sans* retaining wall?

Comment: In the "proposed solution"  the intention is for the outer edge of the post shaft  to be not more than several inches  from the retaining wall. I will be discussing with County permitting whether that is in fact allowed: but in any case it will be less than the *actual* depth of the footer, though not less than code requirement which is only six inches.

Comment: "Not more than several inches" probably means you need to drop your footing down below the frost line at the *bottom* of the wall.

Comment: @Huesmann that may be the case.   I wonder what the county will say. The frost guidelines of 12 inches here are from before the _significant_ climate change effects.  There has been less than one inch ground freezing for years here.  The permitting office may also consider the (boulder/gravel) wall itself provides some amount of insulation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Proposed solution**

*Rebar-reinforced concrete pillar connecting the deck post [above grade] to a full concrete /rebar footer located below the base level of the retaining wall*

Details:

- Post is attached to the pillar via the typical Steel bracket that provides the separation from the soil and thus slows the rotting
- 8" or 10" concrete pillar constructed using a sonatube
- Pillar is seamlessly connected to the concrete footer 30 inches down. This puts the top of the footer six inches below the bottom of the retaining wall
- Footer is 18 inch diameter 12 inch thickness with 2x2 rebar mesh. Note: code is actually just *six* inches, but let's be generous
- Footer rests atop four inches of hardscrabble.
- **Single [concrete] pour for the pillar and the footer**

  - Fill 'er up!

- Calculations [if anyone cares]

- Deck is 130sqft, so the tributary sqft is 33 per each of the 3 posts.
- Post is 6x6 The required depth of the pier depends on the soil bearing capacity and whether using square or cylindrical piers.  Let's determine the first part:
- Soil bearing capacity.  I will use a very thick layer of hardscrabble gravel. A conservative number is 2100 pounds/sq inch but might easily exceed 3K.  I will use the lower number that leaves a large safety margin. Reference:  http://www.geotechdata.info/parameter/bearing-capacity

[image]

**the *Cylindrical Base Footing***

[image]

Six inches is *thin* for a pier, i'll be going with 12 inches
instead.

*Some additional thoughts*  The 24 inches of soil in the retaining wall may not count much for strength but they *do* count for frost protection. More generally it is helpful to understand the engineering and materials actually necessary (and then do a bit more).  In all of my proposed solutions the footer below the base of the retaining wall is already double the amount required by code. The differences is in how *much* more concrete is being used given the extra condition of being on a the retaining wall

Footer calculation:  https://apps.leg.wa.gov/wac/default.aspx?cite=51-51-0507

Answer (score 0):

Your original plan (footing depth *below* the lower grade) is fine. The only problem is your psychological barrier, meaning that you seem to think 48" is absurdly deep. It isn't. In my region frost footings are to 42". Just to my north they're 48", and a bit further they're 60".

Get over that line of thinking and the path becomes clear. One 48" hole is not a big hurdle. A post-hole digger (two-handled contraption) makes it fairly easy.

Comment: The perspective is less about how much digging to do and instead  "how much material and engineering is needed to meet the need/requirement at hand."  Meeting the need and then over-engineering _a bit_ but not excessively is the point of the question and my proposed solutions. That does depend on locale. If you're in the Upper Midwest or Plains states as it seems the need is different.

Comment: I have added details in the question supporting my approach and that this approach is too much concrete.